# Automatically synchronize OneDrive files when edited with specific software on iPad

Tags: pdf, file-management, ios, pdf-editor

Is it possible to edit PDF files, (for example,) with OneNote on my iPad and then those edited files are automatically updated also on my OneDrive? With edit, I mostly mean making notes with the Apple Pencil. I know, you can also edit files straight up in the OneDrive (iOS) App, but the features there are very minimal. I am trying to edit the with OneNote and the changes I make should be automatically updated also on OneDrive. If it is not possible to do it with OneNote, is there another way? I am open for any software recommendation, not only OneNote - that is why i am posting it here on this site.

I know that it does not work with Good Notes or Notability, because you would have to export the edited file again - which leads to extra work, especially when you have a lot of folders and files.

I already found one app, which is Adobe Acrobat for the iPad. But unfortunately, there are not many features to make notes with the Apple Pencil.

I hope this topic suits to this site - it is very hard to find a proper site for this topic.

Comment: - Adobe Acrobat on iOS / iPadOS - Files (Files application from Apple) - PDF Viewer 3.0 - PDF Expert 7

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you cannot edit PDF files. Not on Windows, iOS, whatever.

The only way is to download the [official Acrobat Reader App for iOS](https://www.adobe.com/documentcloud/acrobat/hub/how-to/how-to-read-pdfs-on-ipad) and use that to modify the PDF or add notes with the apple pencil.

Then OneDrive will automatically upload and sync your files.

But I think you need to have the paid version of Acrobat Reade App to make changes for Windows, iOS, whatever.